# Trying to understand templates

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a short example of the confusion that I'm having here:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T Add (T t1, T t2)
{
    std::cout << "<typename T>" << std::endl ;
    return t1 + t2 ;
}

template <int>
int Add (int n1, int n2)
{
    std::cout << "<int>" << std::endl ;
    return n1 + n2 ;
}

template <>
int Add (int n1, int n2)
{
    std::cout << "<>" << std::endl ;
    return n1 + n2 ;
}

int main (void) 
{
    Add (5, 4) ;
    Add <int> (5, 4) ;
    Add <> (5, 4) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
<>  
<>  
<>
```

So I'm thinking, okay, the most explicit specialization gets priority.
But then I remove:

```
template <>
int Add (int n1, int n2)
{
    std::cout << "<>" << std::endl ;
    return n1 + n2 ;
}
```

And the output is:

```
<typename T>  
<typename T>  
<typename T>
```

Why doesn't `template <int>` version get called?
What would cause it to get called?
Why is the purpose of that syntax?

Comment: Good question.  If you want the `int` one to be called, then use `template<typename T = int>` instead of `template<int>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second overload expects an integer, not a type. You'd call it with

```
Add< 42 >( 1, 2 );
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8728db325e8010dc)

To clarify: The second is an independent overloaded function called `Add`, not a specialization. You were probably thinking of something like:

```
template <>
int Add<int>(int n1, int n2)
{
    std::cout << "<T=int>" << std::endl ;
    return n1 + n2 ;
}
```

which is exactly the same as the last specialization you wrote and which would thus conflict with it (redefining it). [**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eae5e18dc875dcd7)

Comment: This answer is missing the solution and it'll be perfect (the solution is in the other answer's you know)

Comment: @user9000 I can't type that fast and I wanted to include live examples for OP to play with :) (Updated answer of course)

Comment: This answers the question of `What would cause it to get called?` and `Why doesn't template <int> version get called?` but the other question asked by the OP is still left unanswered. And I am actually curious as to what the purpose of this is other than providing compile time argument to a template object

Comment: The second overload expects an actual value... I feel stupid now because I knew this. My mind blanked out on me.

Comment: @Smac89 I think it's implicitly answered. OP thought that this "syntax" would specialize the first template, but in fact it creates an overloaded function. You might find a use-case in practice for that but certainly not in an SSCCE :)

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong syntax for the specialization for `int`s. It should be:

```
template <>
int Add<int>(int n1, int n2)
{
    std::cout << "<int>" << std::endl ;
    return n1 + n2 ;
}
```

And if you do that, you'll see that it clashes with the final specialisation due to multiple definitions.

Comment: +1 for the note on ambiguous resolution. Dropping my answer and up-voting this one.